# PHP internal function change langage of returned value

Tags: php, return-value, multilingual

Is there a way to change the return value language of PHP function ? ( from server side, not depending to client machine )

[getdate()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.getdate.php)

```
<?php
$today = getdate();
print_r($today);
?>
```

return

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 40
    [minutes] => 58
    [hours]   => 21
    [mday]    => 17
    [wday]    => 2
    [mon]     => 6
    [year]    => 2003
    [yday]    => 167
    [weekday] => Tuesday
    [month]   => June
    [0]       => 1055901520
)
```

I wanted to change "Tuesday" to "Mardi" ( in french ) or any other language..

I didn't find var like "preferred language"..

I put `<html lang='fr'>` " between `<Form>` and `<head>`, doesn't change. I guess I have to put something in my php.ini (or somewhere else).

If this is the solution ( perhaps someone will give me the exact line to put in and where) and so, I will have a second question: How to manage different websites with different preferred language because this solution will affect main configuration ? I have 1 VPS, with several domain, some in English, some in french...

Thanks.

Comment: Take a peek at [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: I already try, but it doesnt change anything..

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro');
 $loc_de = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo "L'identifiant de l'allemand sur ce système est '$loc_de'";
even this.. took on php website , still "Tuesday" :(

Comment: I just found out this :

 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR@euro');
 echo strftime('%B'); // Give avril ( french)
 var_dump(getdate());// Give April ( English)
 
Any way to have getdate() in french langage ?